# Finding a non-existent Powershell script that apparently exists in PATH

Tags: windows, powershell

I have an old wslcompact script I created from some instructions a long time ago before it was an actual project, and it runs with `wslcompact` command. I'd like to update it to the latest version but I can't find the script I created anywhere. I have tried to search the hard drive recursively with *wslcompact* filter, tried `Get-Command` and `Get-ChildItem`. I also tried to install newer wslcompact but the old one still executes over the newer one.

Does anybody know how to find a script that doesn't seem to exist anywhere, yet apparently can be found in PATH?

Comment: Powershell first looks for cmdlet in the current folder.  Then searches the environmental variable PSMODULEPATH.

Comment: Did you look into `$Profile` ?

Comment: @jdweng: In direct command invocation, PowerShell does _not_ look for commands in the current folder _unless_ explicitly told to do so via a command _path_ rather than a name (e.g, `.\script` instead of `script`). `$env:PSModulePath` is only relevant for commands exported from _modules_, not script files (`*.ps1`).

Comment: @Theo was right, it was indeed in $Profile. I'm really a newbie with Powershell, so I didn't even remember this existed.

Answer (score 0):

- If `wslcompact` is indeed a *script file* (`*.ps1`) or other *external executable* (e.g., `.cmd`, `.exe`) whose directory is listed in `$env:PATH`, you can discovers its full path as follows:

  ```bash
  # If this doesn't report an error but produces no output,
  # the implication is that "wslcompact" is NOT a script file / executable.
  (Get-Command wslcompact).Path
  ```
- If, by contrast, `wslcompact` is the name of a *different command form*, namely a *function* or *cmdlet* or *alias*, discover the specific command form first, and see if it came from a *[module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules)*:

  ```bash
  # If wslcompact comes from a module, the SourceModule property
  # will contain the module's / module manifest's full path.
  Get-Command wslcompact |
    Select-Object CommandType, @{ n='SourceModule'; e={ $_.Module.Path } }
  ```
- If the [calculated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) `SourceModule` property is *empty*, indicating that the command does *not* come from a module:

  - If `CommandType` is `Function`, use the following to get the originating *script file*'s full path (e.g. `c:\path\to\script.ps1`):

    ```bash
    (Get-Command wslcompact).ScriptBlock.File
    ```

    - Chances are, the resulting path indicates (one of) your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file(s).
    - If there is *no* output, the implication is that the function is a *built-in* one, such as `oss` or `help`, or a function *defined interactively in the current session*.
  - If `CommandType` is `Alias`:

    - For a non-module-originated alias you can *not* determine what file it came from, as far as I know, but, there are only 3 possibilities:

      - The alias is *built in* (e.g., `%`, `gci`, `h`)
      - The alias is defined in a `$PROFILE` file.
      - It was defined interactively or from code *in the current session*.